# Filter a DataFrame by Array Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter a dataframe which has a column with categories (*List[String]*). I want to ignore all the rows that have a non valid category. They are not valid when they are not in *model.getCategories*

```
def checkIncomingData(model: Model, incomingData: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  val list = model.getCategories.toList
  sc.broadcast(list)
  incomingData.filter(incomingData("categories").isin(list))
}
```

Unfortunately my approach does not work because categories is a list, not a single element. Any idea who to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

The first problem I see is that you didn't assign the broadcast to a variable.

```
val broadcastList = sc.broadcast(list)
```

Besides you have to reference it using `broadcastList.value`. For instance:

```
incomingData.filter($"categories".isin(broadcastList.value: _*))
```

**NOTE**
@LostInOverflow made an important contribution, he clarified my answer and said that the method `isin` is actually evaluated in the driver, so broadcasting the list doesn't help at all, and more important the list shall be expanded in order to be evaluated.

Comment: broadcast has no effect here.

Comment: Excuse me what? I tried to keep my answer in the dame context of the question

Comment: Think about the order of evaluation. Argument of `isin` is evaluated eagerly on the driver. It is not different than `lncomingData.filter($"categories".isin(list))`

Comment: Are you totally sure? Because I think this might be parallelized, if each node has the list (broadcasted), it could help  to boost the performance. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I am sure. I upvoted because it is useful note but it doesn't resolve the problem. Please check my answer.

Comment: Even if that does not broadcast and it is evaluated in the drive (what I do not really understand why), It does not work.
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'categories IN (1,0)' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type;`

Answer (score 1):

Just expand list:

```
incomingData.filter(incomingData("categories").isin(list: _*))
```

Note: broadcasting won't help you here. This is evaluated on driver.